# Analyze or collect Xamarin stack traces for ANR in google play console

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

We are getting some stack traces for "background" (on broadcast reciever) ANR's in google play console. But there are all looking something like this:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x7523b718 self=0xec085400
  | sysTid=13422 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xef6bb534
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=74 stm=24 core=7 HZ=100
  | stack=0xff1ec000-0xff1ee000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 0000000000017520  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 0000000000047cbd  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL33__pthread_mutex_lock_with_timeoutP24pthread_mutex_internal_tbPK8timespec+520)
  #02  pc 000000000017e45c  /data/app/com.company.package-2/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so (???)
```

so we cannot get any useful information of what happens - analysis of code gives nothing.
Is there any way of collecting C# stacks on ANR event?

Comment: Could you please post the complete error message ? I think we'd likely need to see more message to help you pinpoint the problem

Answer (score 2):

There is a package named Xamarin.ANRWatchDog that detects Android ANR errors (Application Not Responding) available via [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.ANRWatchDog) or from [Github](https://github.com/nwestfall/Xamarin.ANRWatchDog).  It is a thread that watches for ANRs and then raises an error with stack traces for all of the threads. It was ported to Xamarin from [Salomon Brys's ANR-WatchDog](https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog).

Comment: Yes, we already tried to use it. The problem is that it collects nearly identical stacks that we have in Google Play console - the part of stack that I have cut, but there is nothing suspicious in that code, because it is only the code, that was executed before .Net code execution. And the .Net code is hidden somewhere in libmonosgen-2.0.so and other native stack traces