# Why my Xamarin android apps keeps not responding?

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play, android-anr-dialog

I have upload an app to Google app but it keeps not responding although I am not getting any issue on my emulator.

I am getting the below ANR report but it doesn't tell where is the issue to fix? I don't have any thing running for long time in app..

The only thing I am using in the page is just Syncfusion Rotator and buttons to navigate to other pages.

Kindly help...

```
Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON flg=0x50000010 VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null, mFlags=0x00000000)} }


"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x75696598 self=0xab047f08
  | sysTid=20139 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf76a9b50
  | state=R schedstat=( 119604524599 1335738839 21209 ) utm=11496 stm=464 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0xff460000-0xff462000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 0000000000268df0  /data/app/com.jafaria.app-2/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so (???)
  at mono.java.lang.Runnable.n_run (Native method)
  at mono.java.lang.Runnable.run (Runnable.java:30)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7326)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)


"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=3 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c55640 self=0xab2edde0
  | sysTid=20145 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf45b7930
  | state=S schedstat=( 193499302 22057244 1774 ) utm=5 stm=14 core=6 HZ=100
  | stack=0xf44b5000-0xf44b7000 stackSize=1038KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x09f0b00c> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
  at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run (Daemons.java:162)
- locked <0x09f0b00c> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)


"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=4 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c556a0 self=0xab1aa4c8
  | sysTid=20146 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf44b2930
  | state=S schedstat=( 202455359 15652502 1096 ) utm=15 stm=6 core=7 HZ=100
  | stack=0xf43b0000-0xf43b2000 stackSize=1038KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x0666cd55> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:423)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove (ReferenceQueue.java:101)
- locked <0x0666cd55> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove (ReferenceQueue.java:72)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run (Daemons.java:200)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)


"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 Sleeping
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c55700 self=0xab2e33a8
  | sysTid=20147 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf43ad930
  | state=S schedstat=( 11755408 4372035 128 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=6 HZ=100
  | stack=0xf42ab000-0xf42ad000 stackSize=1038KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep! (Native method)
- sleeping on <0x0113836a> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep (Thread.java:1031)
- locked <0x0113836a> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep (Thread.java:985)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepFor (Daemons.java:288)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForFinalization (Daemons.java:299)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run (Daemons.java:247)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)


"Binder_1" prio=5 tid=7 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c5f0a0 self=0xab2ec658
  | sysTid=20149 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf40a5930
  | state=S schedstat=( 83224694 45127544 556 ) utm=3 stm=5 core=4 HZ=100
  | stack=0xf3fa9000-0xf3fab000 stackSize=1014KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 0000000000042d9c  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 000000000004989d  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
  #02  pc 000000000001e947  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+174)
  #03  pc 000000000001eea7  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+6)
  #04  pc 000000000001ef45  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+48)
  #05  pc 0000000000023a11  /system/lib/libbinder.so (???)
  #06  pc 000000000001011d  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+112)
  #07  pc 000000000006082f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+70)
  #08  pc 0000000000041833  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
  #09  pc 0000000000019335  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)


"Binder_2" prio=5 tid=8 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c6a0a0 self=0xab2dedc8
  | sysTid=20150 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf3fa6930
  | state=S schedstat=( 86105629 40224422 567 ) utm=3 stm=5 core=6 HZ=100
  | stack=0xf3eaa000-0xf3eac000 stackSize=1014KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 0000000000042d9c  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 000000000004989d  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
  #02  pc 000000000001e947  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+174)
  #03  pc 000000000001eea7  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+6)
  #04  pc 000000000001ef45  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+48)
  #05  pc 0000000000023a11  /system/lib/libbinder.so (???)
  #06  pc 000000000001011d  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+112)
  #07  pc 000000000006082f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+70)
  #08  pc 0000000000041833  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
  #09  pc 0000000000019335  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)

"Thread-966" prio=5 tid=9 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d510a0 self=0xab339dd0
  | sysTid=20152 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xef27f930
  | state=S schedstat=( 432680303 308431515 2375 ) utm=26 stm=17 core=4 HZ=100
  | stack=0xef181000-0xef183000 stackSize=1022KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 0000000000016998  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 000000000001bc8d  /system/lib/libc.so (sem_wait+62)
  #02  pc 0000000000234244  /data/app/com.jafaria.app-2/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so (???)
```

Comment: I am getting this on Android Device Manager but doesn't tell where is the issue: 08-12 07:33:34.205: E/ActivityManager(1659): ANR in com.jafaria.app (com.jafaria.app/md5f83646d8cf6b6359249af8470321ecb8.MainActivity)
08-12 07:33:34.205: E/ActivityManager(1659): PID: 8633
08-12 07:33:34.205: E/ActivityManager(1659): Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 30.  Wait queue head age: 6174.6ms.)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are writing in C# / Mono the Android Stack trace doesn't show you where your code freezes. The stack trace you have just shows that your code is running some mono code on the main (UI) thread, and that code is locking up for more than 500ms (half a second).

The normal problems are doing something in the UI thread which takes a lot of time. Possibilities are:

- reading or writing disk or database
- network access
- a large complicated calculation

I'd suggest looking at this StackOverflow question which gives ways that you can get a [Xamarin stack track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767706/analyze-or-collect-xamarin-stack-traces-for-anr-in-google-play-console) for an Android ANR.

Comment: but I am not doing any of that? is there any way or tool to know which control or page causing this crash?

Comment: See the link at the bottom of my answer. Answers to that question have a Xamarin ANR tracer. I've never used it, but it sounds like a good idea.